# Proof of Wedderburn Theorem (Henderson's) confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

In this page 2 of this [article](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/NZJMaths/nzjmaths022/nzjmaths022-01-010.pdf), the author provides a proof of Wedderburn's Theorem.

> If $R$ is a simple ring, with a minimal left ideal, then $R \cong M_n(D)$ for some $n \ge 1$, $D$ division ring.

What I do not understand is the argument here.

> Let $K$ be minimal left ideal... If $\dim_D K$ is infinite , the set $$S = \{ \alpha \in End_D(K) : \alpha(K) \text{ is finite dimensional } \}$$ is a proper ideal of $End_D(K)$, contrary to simplicity of $R$.

**My confusions:**

(i) I don't see how the set is proper: I only see $0 \in S, Id \notin S$.

(ii) How does this contradict simplicity of $R$?

Comment: The biggest gap is that you haven't mentioned if/why you know $R\cong End_D(K)$. Once you know that, it's a bit incomprehensible that you're saying you know $1\notin S\subset R$, but don't understand why $S$ is a proper subset.  As egreg says, $S$ is obviously also nonzero. Then as for ii), that contradicts simplicity *by definition*.

Comment: I think I was just confused about (ii). It is clear looking back now. But for (i) why cannot $S = \{ 0 \}$? (So it is not necessarily proper. )

Comment: typically "proper" means "not the entire set" and "nontrivial" means "not 0 and not $R$". But to answer your question, you can take any basis $\{b_1,\ldots\}$ for $K$ over $D$, then you can map $b_1\to b_1$, and $b_i=0$ for all other indices. This completely determines a nonzero homomorphism with $1$-dimensional image. So... $S\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: Catching up on the comments below, this is exactly what egreg has already suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $K$ is infinite dimensional over $D$. Then the identity doesn't belong to $S$, so $S$ is a proper subset of $\operatorname{End}_D(K)$.

Now prove $S$ is an ideal of $\operatorname{End}_D(K)$.

1. $0\in S$ is obvious
2. If $\alpha,\beta\in S$, then $\alpha+\beta\in S$ because…
3. If $\alpha\in S$ and $\beta\in\operatorname{End}_D(K)$, then $\alpha\beta$ and $\beta\alpha\in S$ because…

The ideal $S$ is nonzero: take a one-dimensional $D$-subspace of $K$ and the projection on it is a nonzero element in $S$. With more details: let $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis for $K_D$; fix an index $i_0$ and consider the linear map $\alpha\colon K\to K$ defined on the basis by $\alpha(x_{i_0})=x_{i_0}$ and $\alpha(x_i)=0$ for $i\ne i_0$. Then $\alpha\ne0$ and $\alpha\in S$.

Since $R\cong\operatorname{End}_D(K)$, this is a contradiction to $R$ being simple.

Comment: Why can't $End_D(K) =\{ 0\}? $ Also how did you get $R \cong End_D(K)?$

Comment: @CWL The endomorphism ring of a nonzero vector space is nonzero; but if the identity doesn't belong to $S$, how can the endomorphism ring be $\{0\}$, since $0\in S$?. The isomorphism is stated and proved a few lines earlier in the proof.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why $S = \{ 0 \}$

Comment: @CWL Take the projection to a one-dimensional subspace. This is a nonzero endomorphism in $S$.

Comment: I tried something like that but was unsure. This was what I thought: Let $\{ x_i \} $ be basis of $K$, as a right vector space over $D$. Then $\pi:K \rightarrow K$, $k= \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i d_i  \mapsto   x_i d_i  $ is well-defined, where $d_i \in D$. We then have, $\pi(d \cdot k) = \pi(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i d_i d ) =  x_i d_i d = d \cdot x_i d_i = d \cdot \pi (k)$, for all $d \in D$, hence a $D$-module endomorphism. Are $End_D (K) $ all the "right $D$-module homomorphisms? I think I was getting confused by left and right.

Comment: I think I should have written the projection as, for some fixed $j$,
$$ \pi (k \cdot d) = \pi ( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i d_i d ) = x_j d_j d = \pi(k) \cdot d $$ 
for all $d \in D$. I hope this correct (?)

Comment: @CWL Yes, a fixed index is what's needed.